# symfony doctrine using setters and getters dynamically

Tags: php, oop, symfony, doctrine

I'm using symfony and doctrine.

The server gets a HTTP PATCH request for the URL /company/{id} containing the property of a model and its value like `{"name": "My new name"}` The new value needs to be persisted into the DB.

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$requestContentJSON = $request->getContent();
$requestContentObj = json_decode($requestContentJSON);

$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Company');
$company = $repository->find($id);
```

Now I could just enter `$company->setName($requestContentObj[0]);` but the property being received will vary. Right now I'm using the following code to be able to handle every property:

```
foreach($requestContentObj as $key => $value){
    switch($key){
        case 'name':
            $company->setName($value);
            break;
        case 'department':
            $company->setDepartment($value);
            break;
        case 'origin':
            $company->setOrigin($value);
            break;
        case 'headquarters':
            $company->setHeadquarters($value);
            break;
        case 'email':
            $company->setEmail($value);
            break;
        case 'twitterid':
            $company->setTwitterId($value);
            break;
        case 'description':
            $company->setDescription($value);
            break;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't look very smart especially because I know that I will have other entities like news, products, users, etc that will have their properties updated in the same manner. I'd like to do something like this:

```
$company->set("property", "value");
```

First thought that crossed my mind was to put this switch statement inside the company class inside this set function and also inside all the other entity classes I have. But is there a better way? Maybe symfony/doctrine has the solution already built-in, but I didn't find anything that would suit me.

I still want to use setters and getters as a long-term investment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you'll have the property names similar to method names.

You can do something like this. To set multiple properties.

```
Class customer {

    protected $_email;

    public function __construct(array $config = array()){
         $this->setOptions($config);
     }

    public function getEmail(){
        return $this->_email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email){
        $this->_email = $email;
    }

    public function setOptions(array $options)
    {
        $_classMethods = get_class_methods($this);
        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            $method = 'set' . ucfirst($key);
            if (in_array($method, $_classMethods)) {
                $this->$method($value);
            } else {
                throw new Exception('Invalid method name');
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function setOption($key, $value){
        return $this->setOptions(array($key, $value));
    }

}
```

Now you can simply do this:

```
$array = array('email' => 'abc.@gmail.com');
$customer = new Customer($array);
echo $customer->getEmail();
```

Comment: +1 because this is a good general purpose solution that works outside a symfony/doctrine context. Incudentally, you can excise the `ucfirst()` because PHP method and function calls are actually case insensitive!

Comment: Jay, thank you for your help! Although @Darragh just showed me an alternative for getters and setters which is to use the annotation validations of symfony. It supports callback, so apart from validating I can also log an error if I want to which sort of renders getters and setters useless. Otherwise I'd have implemented your approach to the problem.

Comment: @yurihbss don't forget to upvote Jay if you think his answer was useful :)

Comment: @yurihbss This method was supposed to be used in a class context. Sorry I forget to mention that I have updated my answer.

Comment: we can also use `method_exists()`

Comment: public function setOption($key, $value)
        {
            return $this->setOptions(array($key => $value));
        }

Answer (score 4):

My inital thought would be to add a `merge` method to your class, like so:

```
<?php

// example Company entity
class Company
{
    private $name;

    function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    function merge(\stdClass $obj)
    {
        // get the object vars of the passed object
        // iterate, and replace matching properties
        foreach (get_object_vars($obj) as $prop => $val) {
            if (property_exists($this, $prop)) {
                $this->$prop = $val;
            }
        }
    }
}

$company = new Company();

// mocking your request object
$requestContentObj = new stdClass();
$requestContentObj->name = 'acme';

$company->merge($requestContentObj);

var_dump($company);
```

Yields:

```
class Company#1 (1) {
    private $name =>
    string(4) "acme"
}
```

This silently dumps any passed values that do not match any properties in your `Company` class, which may or may not be what you want. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your help. This is probably what I want. Correct me if I'm but I think that it wouldn't be wise to directly set the properties even from inside the entity class. If there's a way of implementing your `merge` method still redirecting the values to a setter that would be better right? Then if the need arises I can check the value being passed inside the setter function.

Comment: Good point, it depends! It makes sense to call the method if you have additional input validation (which is of course very common). With Symfony/Doctrine, I tend to use validation annotations on my entities' properties, which sort of negates most of the need for additional logic in entity setters. I use  `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` hooks for calculable/composite fields. That said, this is only one approach - I'd say your point is valid - you very much might want to still use the setters. @Jay's answer addresses this neatly, and I would probably do something pretty similar in that case.

Answer (score 2):

What I can propose is not using the setters, but it seems a good fit for your problem.
In doctrine 1.2.4, you could use DQL as follow:

```
$q = Doctrine_Core::getTable("myTable")->createQuery("q")
        ->update()
        ->where("id = ?", $id);

    foreach($requestContentObj as $key => $value)
    {
        $q->set($key, "?", $value);
    }

    $q->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. This example will probably be useful for me in the future.